# MySQL where last action not 'stop'

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I have a table that stores users name, action(stop,start,pause) and timestamp for action.

Thus the columns are `userid`, `name`, `action` and `timestamp`

How do I get the active users. I.e. users who's last action was not "stop".

More appreciation for helping me construct the query (instead of posting one that works) and/or for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Select`ing a last value of `action` field means aggregate query with `max(timestamp)` query field. In this case you won't be able to pick other fields from the same record for which `timestamp = max(timestamp)`, because it's not allowed to aggregate-query fields without an aggregate function.

So you need a kind of subquery to pick user's last action time. Plus, you will only be able to `join` with it by `timestamp` and `userid` itself.

Now, on to query:

```
select actions.userid, actions.action
from actions
  inner join (select max(timestamp) timestamp, userid from actions group by userid) lastActions
    on actions.userid = lastActions.userid and actions.timestamp = lastActions.timestamp
where actions.action != 'stop'
```

Comment: Worked like a charm after appending `group by actions.userid`. However I still don't understand why the final group by is needed.

Comment: `group by` must be there for `max()` to work - once you use one of these (aggergate functions) in a query, you have to use `group by` or other aggergate function on every field. Otherwise, DBMS won't be able to determine, `userid` of which record  with same `timestamp` to return, if there are several. It's what I do in the `lastActions` subquery.

Comment: just to clarify. To make it work I had to add `group by actions.userid` after `where actions.action!='stop`. Failure to add that would give a wrong count. Thats the group by that remains a mystery.

Comment: It could happen if you have several actions with same `userid` AND `timestamp`. Then, yes, you'll need some way to rid of duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

you should create a select statement that groups all the data by `userid`, and order it by the maximum `timestamp` - this will give you the last action for a user (the action with the biggest `timestamp` per group).

all is left to do now is just filter out the groups that do not have a **stop** action as a last action.

- **HINT** - lookup the `HAVING` statement in MySQL for the filtering part

Comment: I had tried this earlier before posting the question.  Victors answer explains why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I assure the difficulty comes in because a user may have many actions:

**1,mjuaji,stop,00002323**

**1,mjuaji,start,00002324**

**1,mjuaji,pause,00002325**

**um, to point you to the right direction:**

you could start by thinking about **how to select the last action of each user first**.
try grouping, aggregate operators (max,min...)

then see if the last action is not "stop".